# segmentation fault while taking array value and sorting the array in c.?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

*I wrote this code to take values from the user in an array and sort it. after taking values it says segmentation fault.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, temp, x;
    int arr[10] = { 11, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99, 0, 45 };
    printf("\n Enter 10 numbers: ");
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[x]);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n Ascending Order of the array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
 ./main

 Enter 10 numbers: 11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
100
exited, segmentation fault
```

Comment: Look at your innermost loop: You increment `i`, where you want to increment `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(j=i+1;j<10;i++)
  {
    if(arr[i]>arr[j])
    {
      temp=arr[i];
      arr[i]=arr[j];
      arr[j]=temp;
    }
  }
```

In the inner loop, you are incrementing **i**'s value instead of **j** which is trying to access an array out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Core Dump/Segmentation Fault occurs when you are trying to access a memory through your program that does not belong to you.

One way to prevent this is to increment the value of i until it reaches 9. Thus, the block of code within the if statement of the loop will continue until the subscript of the array is 9.

```
for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: What you describe is a common pitfall in bubble sort, but where did you get that code from? The original code in the question uses `i` and `j`, never `i + 1`. (And instead of doing an extra test, one could just loop until `i < 9`, no ?)